# Can Super deal with multiple inheritance?

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

When inheriting from two objects like these

```
class Foo(object):
  def __init__(self,a):
    self.a=a

class Bar(object):
  def __init__(self,b):
    self.b=b
```

I would normally do something like this

```
class FooBar(Foo,Bar):
  def __init__(self,a,b):
    Foo.__init__(self,a)
    Bar.__init__(self,b)
```

How does super know if I want to call both? and if so how will it know which argument to pass where. Or is it simply not possible to user super here?

Even if Foo and Bar take the same arguments can `super` deal with this?

Or should I not be trying to do this kind of this in the first place?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Correct way to initialize when superclasses accept different arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029550/python-correct-way-to-initialize-when-superclasses-accept-different-arguments)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `super()`, `__init__()` and multiple inheritance is a bit tricky.

In the normal flow of things, *every* method calls `super()`, with the classes that inherit only from `object` doing a little extra work to make sure that the method actually exists: it'll look a bit like this:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def frob(self, arg):
...         print "Foo.frob"
...         if hasattr(super(Foo, self), 'frob'):
...             super(Foo, self).frob(arg)
... 
>>> class Bar(object):
...     def frob(self, arg):
...         print "Bar.frob"
...         if hasattr(super(Bar, self), 'frob'):
...             super(Bar, self).frob(arg)
... 
>>> class Baz(Foo, Bar):
...     def frob(self, arg):
...         print "Baz.frob"
...         super(Baz, self).frob(arg)
... 
>>> b = Baz()
>>> b.frob(1)
Baz.frob
Foo.frob
Bar.frob
>>>
```

But when you try to do something similar on a method that `object` actually has, things get a little dicey;  `object.__init__` doesn't take arguments, so about the only safe way to use it is to call `super().__init__()` with no arguments, since that call *might* be handled by `object.__init__`.  But then it might *not* be handled by `object.__init__`, and instead handled by a class elsewhere in the inheritance graph.  Thus *any* class which defines `__init__` in a multiple inheritance class heirarchy must be prepared to be called with *no arguments*.

one way of dealing with this is to never use arguments in `__init__()`.  Do minimal initialization, and rely on setting properties or using other means to configure the new object before use.  That's pretty unpleasant, though.

Another way is to use only keyword arguments, something like `def __init__(self, **keywords):` and always remove the arguments that apply to the given constructor.  This is a hope based strategy, you *hope* that all of the keywords get consumed before control reaches `object.__init__`.

A third way is to define a superclass to all of the multiple-inheritable bases which itself defines `__init__` in some useful way and does *not* call `super().__init__` (`object.__init__` is a no-op anyway).  This means you can be *sure* that this method is always called last, and you can do whetever you like with your arguments.

Comment: Related: [Understanding Python super() and init methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/)

Answer (score 2):

> Or should I not be trying to do this kind of this in the first place?

Correct. You should be calling only one parent line of `__init__`s, not a tree. `super` will use the MRO to do a depth-first search of the parent classes looking for the proper `__init__` to call. It will not and should not call all possible `__init__`s.

Comment: But what if I want to :) Say I have a class `A`, and I want new threaded class `B` that behaves like `A`. Do I not need to call `__init__` for both `threading.Thread` and `A`?

Comment: Use composition instead of inheritance when it makes your life easier.

Comment: @GP89: That may be ground for another question (eg, How can I refactor MI to use composition..)