# calling init for multiple parent classes with super?

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, init, super, new-style-class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can Super deal with multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903398/can-super-deal-with-multiple-inheritance)

Python inheritance? I have a class structure (below), and want the child class to call the `__init__` of both parents. Is this possible to do in a 'super' way or is it just a terrible idea?

```
class Parent1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 1

class Parent2(object):
    def _init__(self):
        self.var2 = 2

class Child(Parent1, Parent2):
    def __init__(self):
        ## call __init__ of Parent1
        ## call __init__ of Parent2
        ## super(Child, self).__init__()
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Invocation via `super` doesn't call all the parents, it calls the next function in the MRO chain. For this to work properly, you need to use `super` in all of the `__init__`s:

```
class Parent1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Parent1, self).__init__()
        self.var1 = 1

class Parent2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Parent2, self).__init__()
        self.var2 = 2

class Child(Parent1, Parent2):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Child, self).__init__()
```

In Python 3, you can use `super()` instead of `super(type, instance)`.

Comment: I read many other questions and answers, yours is the only one that pointed out how `super()` calls the "next function in the MRO chain".  A simple yet very important statement indeed.

Comment: For those that have no clue what MRO is: https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/

Comment: What about if Parent1 and Parent2 are built in module classes?

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct and I agree with @Sven in his answer.

I did a simple test on Python 3.7 and `super()` did call `__init__()` from all the parents.

If you call a method that exists in both parent classes, only the method from the *leftmost* parent will be called. But `super().__init__()` will call `__init__` of the parents from the *rightmost* to the *leftmost*.

Answer (score 44):

The idea of `super()` is that you don't have to bother calling both superclasses' `__init__()` methods separately -- `super()` will take care of it, provided you use it correctly -- see [Raymond Hettinger's "Python’s super() considered super!"](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) for an explanation.

That said, I often find the disadvantages of `super()` for constructor calls outweighing the advantages.  For example, all your constructors need to provide an additional `**kwargs` argument, all classes must collaborate, non-collaborating external classes need a wrapper, you have to take care that each constructor parameter name is unique across **all** your classes, etc.

So more often than not, I think it is easier to explicitly name the base class methods you want to call for constructor calls:

```
class Child(Parent1, Parent2):
    def __init__(self):
        Parent1.__init__(self)
        Parent2.__init__(self)
```

I do use `super()` for functions that have a guaranteed prototype, like `__getattr__()`, though.  There are not disadvantages in these cases.

Answer (score 13):

You could just call them directly with `Parent.__init__(self)`:

```
class Parent1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 1

class Parent2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var2 = 2

class Child(Parent1, Parent2):
    def __init__(self):
        Parent1.__init__(self)
        Parent2.__init__(self)
        print(self.var1, self.var2)
```