# super() with multiple inheritance

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, super

This is my example:

```
class FirstBase(object):

    def __init__(self, firstarg):
        self.first = firstarg

class SecondBase(object):

    def __init__(self, secondarg):
        self.second = secondarg

class Child(FirstBase, SecondBase):

    def __init__(self, firstarg, secondarg):
        FirstBase.__init__(self, firstarg)
        SecondBase.__init__(self, secondarg)
```

The problem is that how can I initialize `Child` with the `super()` function, I know that in this case `super().__init__()`will only call `FirstBase`'s `__init__()`.

Comment: You need `FirstBase.__init__` and `SecondBase.__init__` to *also* call `super().__init__` - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16310777/3001761) on the duplicate.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/8013076/3001761