# Multiple inheritance with additional properties

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

What is the best way to deal with an inheritance structure like this:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('A')

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        self.foo = foo
        print('B')

class C(A):
    def __init__(self, bar):
        super(C, self).__init__()
        self.bar = bar
        print('C')

class D(B, C):
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        super(D, self).__init__(foo, bar)
```

Essentially, I want to be able to call:

```
>>> d = D('bar', 'ram ewe')
>>> d.foo
'bar'
>>> d.bar
'ram ewe'
```

Currently, the `super(D, self).__init__(foo, bar)` raises `TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`

**EDIT**

Working answer, thanks to Daniel Roseman.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('A')

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, foo, *args, **kwargs):
        super(B, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.foo = foo
        print('B')

class C(A):
    def __init__(self, bar, *args, **kwargs):
        super(C, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.bar = bar
        print('C')

class D(B, C):
    def __init__(self, foo, bar, *args, **kwargs):
        super(D, self).__init__(foo, bar, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: See also: [super() considered super](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/). Contrary to what the accepted answer of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4029550/395760 claims, it is very much possible.

Comment: Good read! Thanks, delnan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to always ensure the methods are both defined and called using the `*args, **kwargs` syntax. That means they will get the parameters they need and ignore the rest.

Comment: Thanks :) Worked like a charm!